# 3D Camera Selection

Tags: ros, kinect, 3dcamera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For an robotic application which requires 24/7 working in an indoor environment
picking up boxes ( after recognizing using the camera application),
loading the boxes,
drop them at the defined location.

I am looking for an industrial camera solution, initially I decided to go for Sick 3Vistor-T (TOF) before I start with this I want to be sure.

Any suggestions which will be an appropriate solution here in this case ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235525/3d-camera-selection/) by [Jackie_16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26639/jackie_16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-05-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-29**:
Perhaps interesting: [3D Camera Survey](http://rosindustrial.org/news/2016/1/13/3d-camera-survey) on the ROS-Industrial blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How large are your boxes? The resolution of the 3vistor is only 144 x 176 according to the data sheet so that it's rather for big objects. I'd prefer a structured light sensor, like the ensenso from IDS: http://www.ensenso.com/?lang=de. The resolution and accuracy is higher so that it imho fits better to your task.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jackie_16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26639/jackie_16/) on 2016-05-29**:
the target trolley here in the following picture
[link text](http://www.a-und-a.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Trolley_High-300x300.jpg)

How much this IDS sensor cost ?

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-05-29**:
This should be doable with the 3vistor. Price depends on your needed resolution (N10 or N30), price is similar to the Sick, just ask for a quote: https://en.ids-imaging.com/ensenso-stereo-3d-camera.html